# Jupyter Notebook autocomplete not working

Tags: python3, auto-completion, jupyter

I am using Ubuntu 20.04
I installed Jupyter Notebook in a virtual environment I created in a folder.
It's all working fine, but clicking on TAB after a dot isn't showing me the methods available.
Is there anything else I should install for autocomplete?

Answer (score 3):

One of the reasons behind this issue can be the crashes of kernel when you try to use the autocompletion. I faced this issue and by observing the logs generated in the terminal used to open jupyter found that every time I try to use the autocompleter, kernel crashes. with the following solution, I resolved the issue in macOs 11.1 Big Sur.

You can just set the Ipython to use something else rather than jedi to do the completion task like pyreadline which can be installed by `pip3 install pyreadline` . But first you have to disable jedi in the Ipython kernel with the following command:

> %config IPCompleter.use_jedi = False

This command will resolve the issue in the current session and if you want to change this configuration in the config file of Ipython kernel you can use the following commands:

> ipython profile create

making a new config file for the ipython in the following directory:
`/Users/zhivarsourati/.ipython/profile_default`

and you can append the following line to the file `ipython_kernel_config.py` generated with the previous command:

> c.IPCompleter.use_jedi = False

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a lot

Comment: This solution worked perfectly for me after getting this error when presing `Tab`:
```
[IPKernelApp] ERROR | Exception in message handler:

...

File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jedi/api/__init__.py", line 725, in __init__
    super().__init__(code, environment=environment,
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'column'
[I 19:35:27.564 NotebookApp] Saving file at /pmat01.ipynb
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, upgrade jedi will do the magic

```
pip install jedi --upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions

jupyter contrib nbextension install --user

pip install jupyter_nbextensions_configurator

jupyter nbextensions_configurator enable --user
```

Then open the `jupyter notebook` and enable the Hinterland under the nbextensions